# For $\frac{(G/H)}{(M/H)}$ to be defined, is it necessary that $M\unlhd G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $M\leq G$. Also, $H\unlhd G$ and $H\unlhd M$. For $\frac{(G/H)}{(M/H)}$ to be defined, is it necessary that $M\unlhd G$?

A premilinary investigation shows not, but I can't find a counter-example to prove my hunch, or prove the converse.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is defined as a coset space always. To make it a group, you need $M$ to be normal in $G$ (equivalently $M/H$ to be normal in $G/H$).

Comment: @BorisNovikov- for $\frac{(G/H)}{(M/H)}$ to be a group

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- I'm not talking about $G/M$.

Comment: You might be referring to the fact that $\frac{(G/H)}{(M/H)}$ is isomorphic to $G/M$. But that is only when $M\unlhd G$. This is not assumed here.

Comment: As I said, $M/H$ being normal in $G/H$ (which is clearly needed to get a group here) is equivalent to $M$ being normal in $G$.

Comment: Oh. OK. I suppose my hunch was wrong then. I'll work on the proof.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft- Can I please see a rigorous proof? I really can't work it out. Let us assume that $M\not\unlhd G$. Then $\exists g\in G$ and $m\in M$ such that $gmg^{-1}\notin M$. If  $m\in H$, or $g\in H$ (or both), it seems entirely possible that $\frac{(G/H)}{(M/H)}$ is a group.

Comment: If $gmg^{-1} \not\in M$ then $(gH)(mH)(gH)^{-1} \not\in M/H$, so $M/H$ is not normal in $G/H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt- Assume for a moment that $g\in H$. Then $g^{-1}\in H$ too. Hence, $(gH)=(gH)^{-1}=H$. This implies $(gH)(mH)(gH)^{-1}=mH$, which belongs to $M/H$.

Comment: I think you are making the assumption that $m\notin M$ and $g\notin M$.

Comment: I am assuming, exactly as you did, that $M \not\unlhd G$. As you said yourself, it follows that there exists $g \in G$ and $m \in M$ with $gmg^{-1} \not\in M$. I concluded from that $(gH)(mH)(gH)^{-1} \not\in M/H$, and hence that $M/H \not\unlhd G/H$.

Comment: @DerekHolt- Haha yes I realised that I was forgetting the fact that $H\unlhd M$. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the correspondence theorem.

It gives you a correspondence of subgroups $U\le G$ containing $H$ and subgroups $U/H \le G/H$. This is a bijective mapping that maps normal subgroups onto normal subgroups.

In your case: $M/H \unlhd G/H$ if and only if $M\unlhd G$.

Comment: Can I please see a rigorous proof? [Correspondence theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Correspondence_Theorem_(Group_Theory)) assumes that $N\unlhd G$ already.

Comment: But the $N$ there is your $H$ and the $H$ there is your $M$. So of course it is assuming that $N \unlhd G$, just like your are assuming that $H \unlhd G$.